# Generate arrays of numbers in certain algorithm

Tags: javascript

So I need few `arrays`:

```
array 1 = [1,9,17,25,33,41];  
array 2 = [2,10,18,26,34,42];
```

etc.
So each `array` adds up 8 to the last item.
But, I need to generate this dynamically (using functions in JavaScript).

Comment: You won't get any code here

Comment: Please show us that you've made some effort already. We can help you with where you've gone wrong.

Comment: someone just posted me an answer and someone else deleted it, whoever posted i like to thank him.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```js
var initValue = 5;
var diff = 8;
var len = 5;

function makeDiffArray(initValue, diff, len) {
  for (var i = 0, arr = []; i < len; i++) {
    arr.push(initValue);
    initValue += diff;
  }
  return arr;
}
console.log(makeDiffArray(initValue, diff, len));
```

Comment: Whilst I like this answer, why give the OP all the code, when they haven't shown any effort on their part?

Comment: @evolutionxbox That is the reason I had deleted it.. Later thought of keeping it...

Comment: Thank you. My brain completely stopped while thinking this thing out.

Answer (score 2):

Something like this?

```js
for(var i = 1; i<10;i++){
  eval("var array" + i + " = [" + i + "];");
  for(var j = 1; j<10; j++){
    eval("array" + i + ".push(array" + i + "[array" + i + ".length] + 8);");
  }
}
```

Comment: I think the OP would want both lines wrapped in another loop to define the first array item number (array1 starts with 1, array2 with 2, etc).

Answer (score 1):

You can also try dynamic variable names

```
var arrayCount = 2;
var initValue = 5;
var diff = 8;
var len = 5;

for(var i=1; i<=arrayCount; i++) {
    window['array'+i] = makeAnArray(i,diff,len);
    alert(window['array'+i]);
}

function makeAnArray(initValue) {
  var anArray = [];
  for (var j = 0, init = initValue; j < len; j++) {
    anArray.push(init);
    init += diff;
  }
  return anArray;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I know this has already been accepted, just wanted to add the ES6 version here.

```js
let [init, diff, len] = [5, 8, 5], tmp = init;
let arr = Array(len).fill(init).map( (x, i) => (i) ? tmp += diff : x );
console.log(arr)
```